# Overlap the content of div on other

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I am creating a drawer look alike functionality.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nitj2021/YyN6k/3/

`$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");`

**its working on chrome only**. 
Now click on Slide Panel it will show the Drawer .
Now I do not want to move the content that is already shown on the page. the drawer should overlap the content.

Answer (score 2):

Group p elements into div and give

```
position:absolute;
```

for that div.

[**look here**](http://jsfiddle.net/YyN6k/4/)

[**Tutorial from Tutorial-point**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=jquery_147)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#hide").click(function(){
     $(".target").hide( "slide", 
                 { direction: "right"  }, 2000 );
  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
     $(".target").show( "slide", 
                  {direction: "right" }, 2000 ); });
  });
```

This may helpful to get your goal. Hope it helps:)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4y8V/)

Comment: I believe the poster probably still wants the words "Slide Panel" to move. Also, just adding position absolute doesn't make the slide div overlap the rest of the content.

Comment: @MathewMacLean yes i want to move "slide panel" along with that

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use `position:absolute;` on the div you want to overlap the rest.

You may want to wrap the div and the button in a div and apply it to that as I have here...

http://jsfiddle.net/YyN6k/8/

Comment: This only works in chrome, as reported in the posters initial question.

Comment: @Dijon can the same will be achieved horizontally . like on clicking that it will be come out from right.

Comment: [**This question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629479/slidetoggle-from-right-to-left) has more on how you could do it, you would either need to do it using `.animate()` and some CSS properties or use jQuery UI `.slide()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:absolute` on the `#panel`